# Evolution Operator of $H = Z_\text{A} \otimes X_\text{B}$ on a Coupled Qubit System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-computer, time-evolution, hilbert-space

I have a Hamiltonian in the tensor product space of a two-qubit system:
\begin{align}
H = Z_\text{A} \otimes X_\text{B}
\end{align}
and am to compute the time evolution operator in order to show that it applies A-controlled X-rotations to B, in the end it should look like:
\begin{align}
U_\text{AB}(t) = e^{-itH} = |0_\text{A}\rangle \langle 0_\text{A}| \otimes e^{-itX_\text{B}}+ |1_\text{A}\rangle \langle1_\text{A}|\otimes e^{itX_\text{B}}.
\end{align}

My approach was to write the exponential in both subspaces and express it in trigonometrical form:
\begin{align}
U_\text{AB}(t) = e^{-itH}  = e^{-itZ_\text{A}} \otimes e^{-itX_\text{B}} = \cos(t) \mathbb{1}_\text{A} - i \sin(t)Z_\text{A} \otimes \cos(t) \mathbb{1}_\text{B} -i \sin(t)X_\text{B}.
\end{align}

**But I got stuck there and don't know whether my first assumption can actually be made.** I feel I'm lacking deeper understanding of how exactly the tensor product works. I would be grateful for any kind of advise.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The Hamiltonian can be written as $H = Z_A\otimes X_B = (|0_A\rangle\langle0_A|-|1_A\rangle\langle1_A|)\otimes X_B$, where we have expanded $Z_A = |0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|-|1_A\rangle\langle 1_A|$ in its eigenbasis. the evolution operator can be written as 
$$U_{AB} = e^{-iHt} = e^{-i(|0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|-|1_A\rangle\langle 1_A|)\otimes X_B t}$$
$$ = \sum_n (-it)^n (|0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|-|1_A\rangle\langle 1_A|)^n\otimes X_B^n $$
Now, $(|0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|)^2 = |0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|0_A\rangle\langle 0_A| = |0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|$
$\Rightarrow (|0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|)^n = |0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|$. Similarly, we have $(|1_A\rangle\langle 1_A|)^n = |1_A\rangle\langle 1_A|$.
Also, as $|0_A\rangle$ and $|1_A\rangle$ are orthogonal states, we have all cross terms vanishing: $\langle 1_A|0_A\rangle = 0 = \langle 0_A|1_A \rangle$. This leaves us with the following:
$$U_{AB} = \sum_n (-it)^n (|0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|+(-1)^n|1_A\rangle\langle 1_A|)\otimes X_B^n $$
$$ = |0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|\otimes\sum_n (-it)^n  X_B^n+|1_A\rangle\langle 1_A|\otimes \sum_n (it)^n X_B^n $$
$$ = |0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|\otimes e^{-i X_B t}+|1_A\rangle\langle 1_A|\otimes e^{i X_B t}$$
And hence, you get the required time evolution! Here, we have assumed that $\hbar = 1$ ofcourse. It can be put back in the appropriate place to get-
$$ = |0_A\rangle\langle 0_A|\otimes e^{-i X_B t/\hbar}+|1_A\rangle\langle 1_A|\otimes e^{i X_B t/\hbar}$$

Answer (score 0):

- Your mistake is that you assume $e^{A\otimes B}=e^{A}\otimes e^{B}$.  This is wrong - just as, in analogy, $e^{ab}=e^a\,e^b$ is wrong for numbers $a$ and $b$. (Indeed, if $A$ and $B$ are just numbers, tensor product boils down to the normal product.)
- A very useful fact is that for any $M$ with $M^2=I$, 
  $$
  e^{-iMt} = \cos(t)\,I - i\,\sin(t)\, M
  $$
  which you can easily check from the Taylor series.
- Note that $M=Z_A\otimes X_B$ has the property that $M^2=I$.